# Using Alt+left/right to switch between panes in tmux

Tags: tmux

I am trying to configure tmux to switch between panes using alt-left, alt-right sequences. This is what I have in my .tmux.conf

```
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. On my machine, alt-left and alt-right are bound to move the cursor one word length at a time

How should I do? thanks

Comment: What does _"On my machine"_ mean? In your terminal emulator, shell, desktop environment, ...? Change to binding on your machine to Ctrl+Left resp. Ctrl+Right.

Comment: well, please ignore it. it's just terminal/shell

Comment: Terminal and shell are two different things, e.g. I'm currently using Tilix as my terminal emulator and zsh as my shell. Both can be independently configured. A terminal is even something completely different. Where exactly are the bindings configured.

Comment: Or can I use win(or command in mac) + left/right?  As I know,  in tmux conf I can set M-Left or S-Left (M is alt, S is shift)。How I use win( or command in mac)?

Comment: Are you running a system with X11?

Comment: thanks for your reply. it is in .tmux.conf

Comment: The solution depends on your system configuration. Does your system run with X11?

Comment: in ubuntu on Remote server。 my pc is mac

Comment: You can try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112163/tmux-key-bind-like-to-use-the-windows-super-for-my-meta-key-in-tmux-without-x  and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1636/how-do-i-bind-the-tmux-prefix-to-a-super. AFAIK MacOS is a real Unix.